# Материал для ios разработки на русском

Tags: xcode, ios

Может кто-нибудь подскажет материал для `ios` разработки на русском. 
Скачал много книг, но они мне не понравились, там описывается примеры.
Меня же интересует  сейчас только описание стандартных классов, их методов, событий. 
Т.е. по сути тоже что и в документации `apple`, но только можно ли найти где-нибудь это на русском?

Comment: а чем вам английский не угодил?

Comment: плохо по английски понимаю

Comment: тогда вам будет очень трудно добиться чего-то серьезного в программировании. Уж что-что, а уметь читать техническую документацию на английском обязан любой нормальный программист.

Comment: у меня опыт программирование 5 лет. только в web. сейчас думал с xcode побаловаться

Comment: Пять лет это опыт программирования или опыт работы программистом? Это, знаете ли, две ооочень большие разницы

Answer (score 3):

Из того, что у меня нашлось на русском: [**Программирование на Objective-C 2.0**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785979001319&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0) и [**Язык программирования Objective-C**](http://steps3d.narod.ru/tutorials/objective-c-tutorial.html).

Ни одну из них не могу посоветовать (не читала). А вообще литературы для разработки под Mac/iOS на русском на порядок меньше, чем на английском. Да и сама Apple не парится с переводом документации: типа, кому надо прочитать — выучат английский :) .

Edit: Вот еще одна книга для совсем начинающих: [**Objective-C. Программирование для iOS и MacOS**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785459015676&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0).

Comment: Не только на порядок меньше, но еще и с опозданием на 2 года в среднем, а релиз версий сдк с новыми фичами (причем частенько серьезными типа АРК или блоков) выходит каждый год

Comment: WWDC - наше все... братья iOS'ники

Comment: первая книга подойдет для начала, я читал

Answer (score 1):

Чтоб изучить ios многого не надо. Я прочитал книгу [**Программируем на iPhone и iPad**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785496010832&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0). Правда, опыт программирования Flex + Java EE дает своё, и немало. Но мне кажется, книга действительно легка в усвоении. Плюс лекции от Lynda.com на англ., но с картинками. И ещё одно главное правило: Какой язык выбрать для изучения первым? Ответ: Английский.   А потом хоть Ассемблер. Книг достаточно на русском, но на англ. лучше раз, актуальней 2. Если ты не читаешь документацию от производителя, ты не программист и нет смысла с тобой работать вообще. Стадию изучения английского я прохожу таким образом: Установил расширения Lingvo ABBYY для Dictionary — стандартная прога для Mac OS X — и при чтении английскоий pdf`ки (советую прогу Skim) юзаю  CMD+CTRL+D и читаю перевод, очень удобно. И сейчас я эти кнопочки нажимаю всё реже и реже. И могу даже разговаривать по англ. чутка :) .

Answer (score 0):

Я брал книгу [**iOS 5 SDK. Разработка приложений для iPhone, iPad и iPod touch**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=978-1-4302-3605-4%2C+978-5-8459-1785-0&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0), написано понятно и информативно. Книжка хороша, как и все книги от этого издателя.

Но мне больше понравилось пройти уроки [imaladec](http://www.imaladec.com/story/content-lessons) и [idev.by](http://idev.by/category/ios/). Там ты получишь базовые знания для того, чтобы ориентироваться, и отталкиваясь от этого базиса, тебе изучать дальше будет на порядок проще. И ещё очень советую англоязычного [raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials). Хоть и на английском, но там очень толково.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогли книги "[**Разработка игр для iPhone и iPad**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785496002158&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)" Тодда Мура и "[**Разработка и продажа программ для iPhone и iPad**](http://findbook.ru/search/d0?ptype=4&pvalue=9785977506878&r=0&s=1&viewsize=15&startidx=0)" Дмитрия Елисеева. Отличные книги: в первой всё довольно подробно изъясняется, а во второй есть отличные примеры, включая примеры с Box2D.